# How to read XLS File using OleDbConnection Class (or anything else)?

Tags: c#, io, oledbconnection

```
private void readXLSData()
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\nsharifzadeh\\Desktop\\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""");
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
```

I used the debugger, and it seems to be working all the way to `da.Fill(ds)` then it bombs saying:

`*The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.*`

I swear the name of the Sheet is Sheet1! Is there anything I am doing wrong here??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What s the name of the worksheet? (on The Tab) at the bottom, is it worksheet, or have you renamed it?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try, sometimes the sheet name requires '' around it...like 'Sheeet1$'

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from ['Sheet1$']", con);
```

if that doesnt work.  Try this on your connection.

```
DataTable schemaTable = con.GetSchema("TABLES");
foreach (DataRow dataRow in con.Rows)
{
    //tablename = rowData[2]  check those contents to see the sheet names in the excel spreadsheet.
}
```

Now I've been working with Excel 12.0 and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, but this shouldn't matter